# Sorting not happening for Datagrid in silverlight 4 for all pages

Tags: .net, sorting, silverlight-4.0

When doing sorting for silverlight datagrid it is happening for one page only.
What am i missing?

Comment: How are you doing your sorting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

[Silverlight 4 – Datagrid (Sorting, Grouping, Filtering and Paging) – Tip of the day](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83906/Silverlight-4-Datagrid-Sorting-Grouping-Filtering-.aspx)